# Wikileaks and GIS Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

So Wikileaks have some GIS data that has been leaked that users of our site have requested (they do not know it is on Wikileaks) but have said I need data X or Y. I will not list the data  in this post as then I am essentially making it public on Stack Exchange but it does exist. Would it be ethical to provide a Wikileaks URL to answer a Stack Exchange question if it would help the user solve their problem? We have one post today that I know of a Wikileaks file that would help.

Comment: This question has a few wikileaks answers http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7758/the-gis-of-war-tracking-conflicts-and-their-effects

Comment: http://sssi.org.au/userfiles/docs/Spatial%20Information%20&%20Cartography/documents_13073568181328900761.pdf provides a Code of Ethics & Rules to those with GISP-AP after their names.

Comment: Questions about Ethics are very difficult to answer, because those change from person to person. Additionally, not everyone on this site is from the US. I for example would not be concerned if you link to the wikileaks data, since I'm not a US citizen, and the US Government has no jurisdiction over me. There is nothing preventing one from linking to that data, except of threat of prosecution by the US  for sharing of classified data. You need to evaluate if this threat is a credible threat for you.

Comment: You'd probably get more insights on this by asking on the [Main Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Agree with @AndreSilva -- this is not so much a GIS question as a SE policy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @AndreSilva (and not contradicted by comments from others), the question raised here is wider than GIS Stack Exchange, and as such would be better researched/asked on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com):

> Meta Stack Exchange is the site where users discuss the workings and
>   policies of the whole Stack Exchange family of Q&A sites. It is
>   separated from the main Q&A to reduce noise there while providing a
>   legitimate space for people to ask how and why this site works the way
>   it does. Meta is for...
>
> - ...Meta Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other about Meta Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or
>     about policies and community decisions)
> - ...Meta Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack Exchange the company (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new
>     features), and
> - ...Stack Exchange to communicate with the community (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect
>     the whole network)
>
> Lots of topics are fair game, as long as they are about the Stack
>   Exchange family of Q&A sites in some way. Any issue that concerns the
>   core Stack Exchange engine that runs all Stack Exchange websites is
>   welcome here.
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before, and
>   avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with the Stack Exchange
>   network. This is not a random discussion area; rather, it's a place
>   for improving our community and website, together.